# Replace cursors with queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Let's say I have a booking covering 6 hours and 3 discounts covering 2 hours each. I want to split my booking into 3 parts so I can allocate 2 hours per discount.

It would return something like this:

```
BookingId 1 | DiscountId 1 | Qty 2
BookingId 1 | DiscountId 2 | Qty 2
BookingId 1 | DiscountId 3 | Qty 2
```

I would then insert those records this into another table.

I'm using an heavily optimized query to determine the number of hours available for each discount. However, I can't find a "good" way to allocate my booking to each discount without using a cursor.

(...)

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    IF @RequiredQty = 0 
       RETURN

    IF @RequiredQty <= @AvailableQty  
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO discount.Usage (DiscountId, BookingId, Quantity) 
        VALUES (@DiscountId, @BookingId, @RequiredQty)

        SET @RequiredQty = 0
    END

    IF @RequiredQty > @AvailableQty  
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO discount.Usage (DiscountId, BookingId, Quantity) 
        VALUES (@DiscountId, @BookingId, @AvailableQty)

        SET @RequiredQty -= @AvailableQty
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM ecursor INTO @DiscountId, @AvailableQty
END

DEALLOCATE ecursor
```

I tried building the corresponding query but I can't select and assign variables at the same time. Using a cursor is not really a problem (besides some potential performance issues) but I was just curious to see if with the newest SQL Server we can convert our old cursors to something better?

Thanks,
Seb

Comment: You've shown sample output which is most helpful. Could you also show sample input. i.e. how many records are going in to create this? Going by your proc it looks like the stock allocation pattern. The twist here is what to do when stuff doesn't match exactly. What order do you assign amounts when there isn't enough / too much

Comment: In most of the case, output would be 2-4 records. The assignment logic is easy here. I can the discount with the highest percentage and allocate my booking to discount until it is fully covered. In terms of inputs, I have a bunch of them. Lots of business logic (ClientId, date, resource)...

Comment: The non cursor solutions I have seen for this involve generating a row id using various permutations of `ROW_NUMBER`, `PARTITION BY` then joining directly on the row number. That's a "gut feel" comment - no specifics provided sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use`CTE RECURSIVE` to make a Table.

like this.

```
DECLARE @BookingId INT = 1;
DECLARE @RequiredQty INT = 2;
DECLARE @Hours INT = 7;

CREATE TABLE #T
(
    BookingId  INT,
    DiscountId INT,
    Quantity   INT
)

;WITH CTE([Count],[Quantity],Rk) AS  
(
    SELECT
           CASE 
                WHEN [HOURS] - @RequiredQty > @RequiredQty THEN @RequiredQty
                ELSE [HOURS] - @RequiredQty
           END ,
           T.HOURS,1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT @Hours [HOURS]
    ) AS T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE  
                WHEN CTE.[Quantity] - @RequiredQty > @RequiredQty THEN @RequiredQty
                ELSE CTE.[Quantity] - @RequiredQty
           END AS [Count],
           CTE.[Quantity] - @RequiredQty, 
           RK + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CTE.[Quantity] - @RequiredQty > 0
)

INSERT INTO #T(BookingId,DiscountId,Quantity)
SELECT @BookingId,Rk,[Count] FROM CTE
option (maxrecursion 0)

select * from #T
```

[image]

[SQLDEMO](http://rextester.com/NFOFU97474)

Comment: Is while more efficient than a cursor?\

Comment: Not much. Its still RBAR. Which is fine for smaller recordsets but slower that a set based solution for very large datasets

Comment: Oh Fancy let me have a try!

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, but don't know if this code has better performance than cursor.

```
DECLARE @DiscountStocks TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DiscountId INT, LastQty INT)
INSERT INTO @DiscountStocks (DiscountId, LastQty) VALUES (1, 5)
INSERT INTO @DiscountStocks (DiscountId, LastQty) VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT INTO @DiscountStocks (DiscountId, LastQty) VALUES (3, 1)

DECLARE @DiscountBookings TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), DiscountId INT, BookingId INT, Qty INT)

DECLARE @BookingDiscount TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), BookingId INT, DiscountId INT, Qty INT)
INSERT INTO @BookingDiscount (BookingId, DiscountId, Qty) VALUES (1, 1, 4)
INSERT INTO @BookingDiscount (BookingId, DiscountId, Qty) VALUES (1, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO @BookingDiscount (BookingId, DiscountId, Qty) VALUES (1, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @BookingDiscount (BookingId, DiscountId, Qty) VALUES (2, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @BookingDiscount (BookingId, DiscountId, Qty) VALUES (2, 2, 2)

SELECT BD.Id AS BDId, DS.Id AS DSId, DS.LastQty, BD.Qty
, DS.LastQty - (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM @BookingDiscount WHERE Id <= BD.Id AND DiscountId = BD.DiscountId) AS QtyAfterSubstract
INTO #LastDiscountStock
FROM @DiscountStocks DS
INNER JOIN @BookingDiscount BD ON DS.DiscountId = BD.DiscountId
ORDER BY BD.Id, DS.Id

INSERT INTO @DiscountBookings (DiscountId, BookingId, Qty)
SELECT DSId, BDId, Qty
FROM #LastDiscountStock
WHERE QtyAfterSubstract >= 0

DROP TABLE #LastDiscountStock

SELECT * FROM @DiscountBookings
```