# Update cursor with a recursive context

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, recursive-query, sql-server-2017

Following with my previous question, I'm trying to update my cursor to use a recursive context. However it seems it's not really straightforward. I can't get the recursive context to loop through my discounts and allocate associated quantity to fully cover my booking.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [discount].[fn_get_eligible_packages]
(
    @TecTacClientId NVARCHAR(255),
    @StartDate      DATETIME2,
    @EndDate        DATETIME2,
    @ResourceId     INT,
    @BookingId      INT NULL
)
RETURNS @discounts TABLE 
(
    [DiscountId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    [Percentage]    INT,
    [StartDate]     DATETIME2,
    [EndDate]       DATETIME2,
    [CoveredQty]    DECIMAL(10,2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF DAY(@StartDate) != DAY(@EndDate) 
       OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) <= 0 
       OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) >= 1440 RETURN

    DECLARE @Qty DECIMAL(10,2), @RequiredQty DECIMAL(10,2) = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0
    DECLARE @DiscountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Percentage INT, @AvailableQty DECIMAL(10,2)

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DiscountId, [Percentage], AvailableQty 
    (...)

    OPEN curs
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @DiscountId, @Percentage, @AvailableQty 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        IF @RequiredQty = 0 RETURN
        IF @RequiredQty > @AvailableQty  SET @Qty = @AvailableQty
        IF @AvailableQty >= @RequiredQty SET @Qty = @RequiredQty

        INSERT INTO @discounts 
        VALUES (@DiscountId, @Percentage, @StartDate, DATEADD(MINUTE, @Qty*60, @StartDate), @Qty)

        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, @Qty*60, @StartDate)
        SET @RequiredQty -= @Qty

        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @DiscountId, @Percentage, @AvailableQty
    END
    CLOSE curs
    DEALLOCATE curs
    RETURN
END
```

Based on the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228325/replace-cursors-with-queries), I tried the following code

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2    = '2018-03-14 10:00:00'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME2      = '2018-03-14 12:00:00'

;WITH CTE (DiscountId, [Percentage], AvailableQty, Qty) AS  
(
    SELECT 
        'f4156db3-a0e3-4324-acf7-04cf2f37325e' AS DiscountId, 
        100 AS [Percentage], 
        10 AS AvailableQty, 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Qty 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        '4f351cda-443a-4d6a-9265-1ea70af0536d' AS DiscountId, 
        100 AS [Percentage], 
        10 AS AvailableQty, 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Qty 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        '51846222-7432-43f7-8647-d2a8e70ea3cf' AS DiscountId, 
        100 AS [Percentage], 
        10 AS AvailableQty, 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Qty 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DiscountId,
        [Percentage],
        AvailableQty,
        CAST(Qty - 
            CASE 
                WHEN Qty > AvailableQty THEN AvailableQty
                ELSE Qty
            END AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Qty < 0
)

SELECT DiscountId, Percentage, Qty FROM CTE
```

For instance, let's say we have following context

- Booking 3 hours long
- Discount 1 has available qty = 1 hour
- Discount 2 has available qty = 0.5 hour
- Discount 3 has available qty = 10 hours

Expected Output

```
Discount 1 > 1 hour
Discount 2 > 0.5 hour
Discount 3 > 1.5 hours
This fully covers my 3 hours long booking
```

Another example

- Booking 1 hours long
- Discount 1 has available qty = 1 hour
- Discount 2 has available qty = 0.5 hour
- Discount 3 has available qty = 10 hours

Expected Output

```
Discount 1 > 1 hour
This fully covers my 1 hour long booking
```

Another example

- Booking 10 hours long
- Discount 1 has available qty = 1 hour
- Discount 2 has available qty = 1 hour
- Discount 3 has available qty = 1 hour

Expected Output

```
 - Discount 1 has 1 hour remaining 
 - Discount 2 has 1 hour remaining 
 - Discount 3 has 1 hour remaining
 This fully does NOT cover my 10 hours long booking. Only 3 hours will be covered by a discount
```

Currently for a two hours long booking I get the following:

```
DiscountId                              Percentage  Qty
f4156db3-a0e3-4324-acf7-04cf2f37325e    100         2.00
4f351cda-443a-4d6a-9265-1ea70af0536d    100         2.00
51846222-7432-43f7-8647-d2a8e70ea3cf    100         2.00
```

Instead of:

```
DiscountId                              Percentage  CoveredQty
f4156db3-a0e3-4324-acf7-04cf2f37325e    100         2.00
```

The problem is caused by this sql

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Qty
```

I should NOT pass the qty with all my discounts. Instead I should keep one shared variable and decrements it. Unfortunately I can't set variable and select at the same time...

Any good idea?

Comment: Sample data would really help

Comment: Actually you can copy and paste my second code sample. It contains some fake data already.

Comment: Output from that query does not match shown output in the question. What output do you expect for that data? It's better if you provide some sample data and desired output from them

Comment: Updated my question with examples and expected behavior. I hope it's clear

Comment: It seems that you do not need neither cursor nor recursive cte. It's clear to me what is `Qty` in your output. Is it an amount of minutes in discount type? How many discount types do you have? What if booking time will be more than sum of times in discounts? Can you show table structure?

Comment: You are correct. Qty represents the number of hours covered by a specific discount. I can have 1-3 discounts that could potentially be used to cover my booking. I added a new example showing what i expect if booking duration more than sum of times in discounts. How could you loop through the discount without cursor/recursive context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query does not use `cursor` or `recursive cte`. Last column in the query calculates amount of minutes covered by each discount. You have not showed your table structures so I created two tables with discounts and bookings.

```
declare @discount table (id int, name varchar(100), duration int)
declare @booking table (id int, startDate datetime, endDate datetime)

insert into @discount 
values (1, 'Discount 1', 60)
    , (2, 'Discount 2', 30)
    , (3, 'Discount 3', 600)

insert into @booking
values (1, '20180314 10:00', '20180314 13:00')
    , (2, '20180314 10:00', '20180314 11:00')
    , (3, '20180314 10:00', '20180316 13:00')
    , (4, '20180314 10:00', '20180314 10:20')
    , (5, '20180314 10:00', '20180314 11:20')

;with cte as (
    select
        *, rTotal = isnull(sum(duration) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)
    from 
        @discount
)

select
    *
from (
    select 
        a.id, a.startDate, a.endDate, b.name
        , iTime = iif(c.diff >= b.rTotal + b.duration, duration, iif(c.diff <= 0, 0, diff))
    from 
        @booking a
        cross join cte b
        cross apply (select diff = datediff(mi, a.startDate, a.endDate) - b.rTotal) c
) t
where
    iTime > 0
order by 1
```

Comment: Indeed it works. let me try to undertand your answer.

Comment: What does sum(duration) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) do?

Comment: It calculates discount time that was applied before current row.